# Determine the function $g$ such that $Y = g(X) \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Let $X \sim U[0, 1]$. Determine the function $g$ such that $Y = g(X) \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$.

I'm pretty lost about this problem. Any help or hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at a general fact. Let $X\sim U[0,1]$ be uniform, and let $F$ be the distribution function of the random variable $Y$. Then the distribution of $F^{-1}(X)$ is that of $Y$. Indeed,

$$P(F^{-1}(X)\leq x) = P(X\leq F(x)) = F(x),$$
where the last equality follows from $X$ being uniform.
Thus you may choose $g$ to be the inverse distribution function for the exponential distribution.